# Subsitution of part of dictionary commands

Tags: tcl

I'm having trouble understanding how to substitute a list of values in dictionary commands.

Would you please tell me what I'm doing wrong/not doing?

Thank you.

```
set comPorts {
    001 {
      socket 123
      user abc
      type http
    }
    002 {
      socket 789
      user abc
      type http
    }
}

# This statement works directly.
#dict set comPorts 002 type port

# These all error.
set path "002 type port"
set path { 002 type port }
set path [list 002 type port]
dict set comPorts $path
chan puts stdout $comPorts
```

Comment: Technically, `port` there isn't the path so much as the terminal value.

Comment: @DonalFellows Thank you. I was really trying to pass `comPorts 002` to a procedure and update its values there. Now with argument expansion I think I can pass that string and use it as `dict with {*}$path { set type port; set sock 345 }` Pretty nice scripting language once it sinks through my thick head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
dict set comPorts {*}$path
```

See documentation at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9

Comment: Thanks. Argument Expansion page 30 of Ousterhout et al. I can remember studying Fig. 2.2 about a year ago when first considering Tcl and then forgetting all about it. Should the link you provided end in #M5 rather than #M9?